# Computer Restart When I Insert a USB Drive (Othe Removable Device)

Tags: windows-xp, hardware-failure

I have faced this issue when My computers just restart when ever I connect a specific memory card, USB drive or any other portable device. This is quite a serious problem which is on the other hand simple to fix if this is happening due to corrupted data on your USB Storage Device.
please give my solution,
If no way to handle this problem, I wanna reinstall my windows xp.

Comment: You say it happens with specific USB devices. Have you checked if they work with another computer? Also, when the computer restarts, do you get the [Blue Screen of Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSOD#Meanings)? If so, what's the error message it displays?

Comment: Also, what happens after the computer restarts? Are you able to log in and use the device normally, or does the computer get stuck in a reboot loop until you remove the device?

Comment: Does this happen with **every** USB port on the computer, or only certain USB ports on that computer?  Have you physically examined the port itself for damage/bent contacts within the port?  Is there anything jammed in there?  Is the plastic center post broken?  Is the port that causes the restart loose in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a simple solution, try this;
In order to fix a removable drive if the data on the drive, you can run scandisk in windows by right clicking the drive icon in my computer, go to right click on pen drive and select properties, now click the tab tools and run a check disk on your pen drive.
you just need to click on check now to start disk checking and repair any errors caused due to corrupted data on your pen drive.
try this, maybe this can help your problem

Answer (score 0):

Its really hard to tell with the information thats there to work out what exactly is the issue. There's two avenues that you can follow if this is an OS related issue.

Follow the blue screens - Turning off rebooting on failure is what's usually suggested, but you can get a good idea of what caused a bluescreen of death with [nirsoft's bluescreenview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) - which lets you look at bluescreen information, or [resplendence software's whocrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed). If its a windows issue, this should tell you what's the driver causing it. Uninstall, and  replace off windows driver service or a known good copy

The other thing i'd consider, though unlikely is a  hardware fault. If the computer reboots from *specific* sorts of usb ports, *independant of os* (so, give linux a shot if the blue screens yield nothing), then there may be a short or other issue somewhere.

I've seen windows systems *freezing* due to a failing hard drive on an ipod as well, but without more information on what's failing, its hard to tell.